# org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:7055 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, mozilla

Selenium Webdriver(2.53) using testNG and java (jdk 8). Mozilla Firefox (46) crashes as soon as page opens gives error message:

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   127.0.0.1:7055 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: I am getting there error message and my firefox browser crashes

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Solved by changing the combination of selenium and firefox.
Selenium version: 2.52.0
Firefox version: 45.2.0
It works for me.